# How to display XML in tree structure in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

How do I get a vanilla XML-file to display like e.g Chrome does (with collapsible, clickable nodes)  using CefSharp WinForms? I suspect `LoadHtml()` is maybe not the right way to do it...

sample XML picked up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85))

current code (`fileName` contains xml-filename):

```
public BrowserForm(string directoryName, string fileName)
{
            InitializeComponent();

            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

            var pathAndFilename = Path.Combine(directoryName, fileName);
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(pathAndFilename);

            _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("localfolder");
            _browser.LoadHtml(fileContent, pathAndFilename);

            HookUpEventHandlers();
}
```

...current output (only spits out text between xml-tags):

```
    Gambardella, Matthew Computer 44.95 2000-10-01 An in-depth look at 
creating applications with XML. Ralls, Kim Fantasy 5.95 2000-12-16 A 
former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her 
own childhood to bec.....
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is no built in functionality for this, you can have a look through the chromium source to see how they implement the transformation. You can search the source online at https://source.chromium.org/chromium you'll have to parse the xml and generate the html/css.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm looking for similar functionality. I've tried both Load and LoadHtml with no luck so far.

Comment: @JimWooley I never got the time to work more on this issue. I've since started to work for another client, so I will [probably] not put effort into it either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide correct `mimeType` in `GetResourceHandler` of `ResourceHandler/ResourceRequestHandler` for this xml file

Example:

```cs
return ResourceHandler.FromString(xml.OuterXml, mimeType: "text/xml");
```